# Почему этот слайдер не работает?

Tags: javascript

Когда нажимаю на next, count++ не работает.

```js
const requestURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'

function sendRequest(url) {
  return (fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }))
}

let arrimg = [];
let count = 0;
sendRequest(requestURL)
  .then(data => {
    data = data.slice(0, 10);
    // console.log(data)
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.append(div);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      arrimg.push(data[i].url);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arrimg.length; i++) {
      let imgs = document.createElement('img');
      div.append(imgs);
      imgs.src = arrimg[i];
      let next = document.querySelector('#next');

      next.addEventListener('click', function() {
        count++
        arrimg[i] = arrimg[count]

      });
      next.addEventListener('click', function() {
        count--
        arrimg[i] = arrimg[count]

      });

      if (i != count) {
        imgs.style.display = 'none'
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<button id="back">BACK</button>
<button id="next">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Подход не верный. Зачем вы в цикле вешаете событие? Не надо так. Самый простой вариант: у вас есть массив картинок. Делаете метод который ставит картинку активной (к прим., интекс с массив + записывает в src), после вешаете события на кнопки, без циклов, и вы просто оперируя индексом опять вызываете выше написанный метод что ставит картинку активной, перед этим "высчитав" нужную

Comment: не получилось..